# How does this recursive function update the TreeView without having an infinite loop?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I got a code in vb.net that allows to display the tree structure of a directory. This code uses a recursive subprocedure (sub) to update TreeView nodes without using any of these methods. I wanted to know how it was possible. Here is the code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Const DirectoryToList As String = "." ' The current in this case

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Defines the first node
        Me.MyTreeView.TopNode = Me.MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(DirectoryToList, DirectoryToList)

        'Tree structure of the first node
        For Each Directory As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryToList)
            Me.MyTreeView.TopNode.Nodes.Add(Directory, Path.GetFileName(Directory))
            'Recursive
            ListFolderTree(Directory, Me.MyTreeView.TopNode)
        Next
        'Files of the first node
        For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToList)
            Me.MyTreeView.TopNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(File))
        Next
    End Sub

    ' ListFolderTree is the "strange" sub whose operation I don't understand

    Sub ListFolderTree(ByVal DirectoryActuel As String, ByVal NodeActuel As TreeNode)
        'Recovers the node in which we are
        Dim Node As TreeNode = NodeActuel.Nodes(DirectoryActuel)
        'Directories of this node
        For Each Directory As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryActuel)
            Node.Nodes.Add(Directory, Path.GetFileName(Directory))
            'Recursive
            ListFolderTree(Directory, Node)
        Next
        'Files for this node
        For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryActuel)
            Node.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(File))
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

And the result is the expected one, so a tree structure.
Could you explain to me what I don't understand about the "ListFolderTree" sub-procedure?
I know that recursiveness can get files and other folders that are themselves in folders higher up in the tree, but how are the data saved in the TreeView control?

Comment: The function only calls itself if the directory `DirectoryActuel` contains subdirectories. Eventually you will reach a directory with no subdirectories and the cycle will be broken.

Comment: @Blackwood: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew it (it's the recursivity principle in this program), but what I don't understand is "how" it works directly at the recursive level of the sub?

Answer (score 0):

At the point where the actual directory has no subdir, the part

```
    For Each Directory As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryActuel)
        Node.Nodes.Add(Directory, Path.GetFileName(Directory))
        'Recursive
        ListFolderTree(Directory, Node)
    Next
```

will be a loop without iterations, because the collection from `Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryActuel)` will be empty, so no other recursive call will be made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do the TreeView nodes update then?

Comment: The nodes were added in <code>Node.Nodes.Add(...)</code>
With two params the first is the name of the node where the new one should be added. For more details about TreeViews and TreeNodes please read the manual, there you will find better and correct information.